# Populate React prop object from async function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

My high level goal here is to be able to read data from text files onto a page I'm creating using React.

I have a utility script file that I'm using to read the file by path:

```
//reader.js
window.readFile = function(filePath, callback) {
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open("GET", filePath, true);
  request.send(null);
  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
      var type = request.getResponseHeader('Content-Type');
      if (type.indexOf("text") !== 1) {
        callback(null, request.responseText);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm calling that function like so in one of my React component files:

```
//component.js
var data = {};

populateData();

function populateData() {
  data.subject = "FILE TITLE";
  data.title = "FILE SUBJECT";
  window.readFile("../path/to/file", function(error, results){
    if (!error) {
      data.content = results;
    }
    else {
      console.log(error);
    }
  });
}

var Content = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <FileContent { ...data } />
    );
  }
});
```

I've tested that the function gets ran correctly from this context, but it would appear that due to the async nature of the readFile function, my data object's content field never gets populated with the text from the file. Is there a synchronous way of returning what I need, or how can I solve this asynchronously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the asynchronous nature of the `readFile` function, you will have to solve this asynchronously. The easiest way to do this would be to add a method to your component that calls the function and then sets the state after it is completed. After it is completed, you can then pass the data to the child component.

For example:

```
var Content = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      data: null
    }
  },

  componentDidMount() {
    this.populateData();
  },

  populateData() {
    const data = {};
    data.subject = "FILE TITLE";
    data.title = "FILE SUBJECT";
    window.readFile("../path/to/file", (error, results) => {
      if (!error) {
        data.content = results;
        this.setState({
          data
        });
      }
      else {
        console.log(error);
      }
    });
  },

  render: function() {
    const {data} = this.state;

    if (data === null) {
      // data has not been loaded yet
      // you can add a loading spinner here or some kind of loading component
      return null
    }

    return (
      <FileContent { ...data } />
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, your example worked out perfectly. Looks like I'll have to do some more reading on the underlying features of the Component class.